# Can I have a web site communicate with my android phone so that sms are triggered on the web site and sent from the phone?

Tags: android, web, text, gateway

I have a project where I want to send a small number of text messages to my client's clients. The automated sms details and timing are stored on a web site and currently, we use an api to an sms provider to send the messages. However, the client has an office mobile phone (android) with unlimited txt account and would like to have the web site send the message details to the android phone so that it can be sent from there at no extra charge. The phone could be connected to a computer via a cable, but it would be best if the details could be sent to the phone via internet. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can create android **app** and push notifications to it from you back-end.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way:**

Just store any thing you want to send somewhere like your database, Then Develop an app for your client that calls your server lets say every 10 second and sends the messages.

**Better way:**

Use google push notification to send data from your website to your client phone!

**Even Better way:**

Tell your client No! Tell him/her that the idea is stupid!